# Data structure calculating time averages

Tags: python, data-structures

```
def sort_message(message):
    total = 0
    counter = 0
    for data in json.loads(message)['data']:
        print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['t'] / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
              "price:", data['p'],
              "volume:", data['v'])
        # for x in json.loads(message)['data']:
        #     p = x['p']
        #     v = x['v']
        #     total += (p * v) / v
        #     counter += 1
        #     if counter == 5:
        #         print(total)


def on_message(ws, message):
    sort_message(message)
    # vwap(message)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    ws.send('{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"BINANCE:BTCUSDT"}')


def vwap(message):
    total = 0
    messages = 0
    for data in json.loads(message)['data']:
        p = data['p']
        v = data['v']
        total += (p*v) / v
    #     messages += 1
    # if messages == 5:
    #     print("VWAP is " + str(total))
    #     counter = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.finnhub.io?token=***",
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

So I'm using Finnhub's API to retrieve real-time data on BTC:USDT price on Binance and I want to calculate what is the volume traded every **n** seconds.

Tried using `time.Sleep` → doesn't work, because it suspends the execution of `vwap()` and it doesn't adds the sum to `total`.

Tried to do some sort of loops in order to execute the function `vwap()` every 5 messages, but the count of the messages is inconsistent so it won't work (this is the commented-out code).

Also tried to implement threading, but it won't run because I can't pass the argument `message` in the initialization of the thread.

Comment: Seems like you could create a background thread that put messages in a `Queue` and process them in a loop in the main thread.